# Pass array on to sql and insert it in link table with one value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

I've found [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097079/c-sharp-sql-server-passing-a-list-to-a-stored-procedure) to pass an array to a stored procedure and [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989560/how-to-pass-a-table-value-parameter) to insert a table into another table. But I want to insert my array in a table as column2 with one other value I have as the value for column1:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (column1, column2)  
VALUES (SELECT @value, column2 from @otherTable)
```

I tried inserting the array into column2 first and then updating column1 to be the one value. But that didn't work and would be insanely expensive anyway.

Is there a reasonable way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then all you need is to get rid of the `VALUES`, like so:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (column1, column2)
SELECT @value, column2 from @otherTable;
```

Comment: Nice Joe. I was just about to post the same thing. You beat me by a few seconds. :D

Comment: Beat me as well... Note to self: answer first, edit later. :-)