# What does SqlDbType.Structured mean?

Tags: c#, sqlcommand, sqlparameter, sqldbtype

From msdn [website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) I get the following:

> A special data type for specifying structured data contained in table-valued parameters.

It seems my code works with it and without it (pushing table to DB using stored procedure).

Can someone explain what does it do - I didn't understand it from the definition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can define stored procedures and you can pass tables as parameter. This is then called a **table valued parameter**.

When you are programming in C#, you can pass such a table-valued parameter to the database by using the `SqlDbType.Structured` constant.

This post shows an example: [How to pass a table-value parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6989560/2504785)

Comment: Is there any way to log structured SqlDbType as a string, right now I'm able to log other types by converting them into string ToString(), but structured type always converts into a blank string.