# How to insert 200 rows into database from Entity Framework in one hit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, stored-procedures

In my MVC 5 application with EF 6.0, I want to insert 200+ records of Product into database using Entity Framework in one hit. 
[1]One way is to convert list of records into XML and pass to Stored procedure. 
[2] If I use  DbContext.Add() , this will fire for every record ( create insert script internally).
[3]If I traverse list of product and pass each record to Stored Procedure, I think this is also not good.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use BulkInsert - there are a few extensions for EF that do that. This is the first I found using a Google Search - [https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Extensions](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Extensions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this question [How to pass a table-value parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989560/how-to-pass-a-table-value-parameter) will work for you but it is exactly what I'm using to load data into a SQL 2014 data base.  Very nice and has been working for 4+ years.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

*(This library is NOT free)*

This library can make your code more efficient by allowing you to save multiples entities at once. All bulk operations are supported:

- BulkSaveChanges
- BulkInsert
- BulkUpdate
- BulkDelete
- BulkMerge
- BulkSynchronize

Example:

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);

// Customize Primary Key
context.BulkMerge(customers, operation => {
   operation.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        customer => customer.Code;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have several productive Web applications that use [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) library with [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6). It works fine, but it is no longer maintained, so a better solution is to use the updated version [EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6-ext](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6-ext).

It is very simple to use:

```
context.BulkInsert(yourListOfModels);
```

and it generates `BULK INSERT` Sql commands that run much faster that classical Enrity Framework individual `INSERT`s.