# how to pass multiple rows with a single column in a stored procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, ssms-2016

how to pass multiple rows using a single column in a stored procedure in SQL (SSMS)?
or
how to pass single column values in a procedure.

```
CREATE TYPE tblAge_Type as TABLE
(
    ID int,
    Age int
)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
alter PROCEDURE spAddAge (
   @datasource tblAge_Type READONLY)
AS
    update tblAge set Age = (select Age from  @datasource ) where Id = (select ID from @datasource )

GO
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @data AS tblAge_Type

INSERT into @data VALUES(1,22) ; 
INSERT into @data VALUES(2,55) ;
INSERT into @data VALUES(3,44);  

EXEC spAddAge @data
```

getting this error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: you could try in simple way `EXEC TestParams 'First', 'Second'
GO`

Comment: Please add more details about your problem and your own efforts this far to solve the problem so that people can help you better. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

there is no standard way to do this.
The most common ways that this is done is:
1) make a comma delimited string, pass it as a parameter, and in the procedure, split the string into a table. There are many string splitting functions around, preferrably use one that does not use loops. I think the latest version of SQL Server has also a string splitting function.
2) pass a table valued parameter, as is explained here: [How to pass a table-value parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989560/how-to-pass-a-table-value-parameter)

Comment: used table- valued parameter. added the code and error in the problem statement

Comment: This is not how it works; you formulated a question, I answered it. The problem you now have is different than the one in the title. You should formulate and submit another question.