# Are .NET DataTables useful beyond as a means of interfacing with databases?

Tags: c#, datatable

I often use the DataTable class in my .NET WCF services, since many of our SPs require TVPs. As far as I know, DataTables are the only way of passing TVPs to SPs.

It just occurred to me that similarly to how `tables`, in which information is stored according to `rows` and `columns` are useful, that the DataTable class may be useful beyond just as a means of interfacing with SQL Server TVPs.

Actually... thinking about this, I have previously written code that iterated over a DataTable's rows, building up an HTML string. However the main reason we used a DataTable as because the same table could be passed to SQL Server as a TVP.

Looking at the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, it looks like you can effectively create relational object models using DataTables.

Would using DataTables be an effective way of caching data retrieved from a SQL Server in a service?

Another potential use-case that comes to mind... Would there be any benefit of using a DataTable for a collection instead of `List<MyType>`?

Comment: DataTables have a lot of overhead.

Comment: "DataTables are the only way of passing TVPs to SPs": [There's at least two other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989560/how-to-pass-a-table-value-parameter).

Comment: Thanks @nvoigt, i didn't know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables are slower than Lists/Enumerables, and its better to use dataAdapter while reading data if you really care about performance.

But Datatables can be really useful as a item source for grids, where you want to just publish whole table data on the UI and no need to specify each column individually as in the case of List.